# Cakephp - get database data from not associated models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I wanted to ask, how can i get data from one table and use this in other find.

For example, i have films table.
I want to get highest rated 3 films. Result should return 3 ID's.

Now, i want to create other query from not associated table, and pass this 3 ID's as "conditions" to find data in other table.

I dont want to use associations, because, data is stored in many databases, and this is problematic.

Thank You.

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: You mean you want to user diffrent table in a diffrent model?

Comment: Yes.
If first result returns array ('32','55','75) how can i use this data to filter results of other find() ?

Comment: Or, how can i pass array of id's to conditions of other find ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got your film IDs you can use `in` to filter the results from your other `Model`:-

```
$filmIds = ['32','55','75'];

$query = TableRegistry::get('Model')->find()
    ->where(function ($exp, $q) use ($filmIds) {
        return $exp->in('film_id', $filmIds);
    });
// WHERE film_id IN ('32','55','75')
```

Check out the docs section on [advanced conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions).

If you need to get your film IDs into the correct format (*i.e.* that shown in the example code) you can use [`Hash::extract()`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html#Cake%5CUtility%5CHash::extract) on the results from your previous query.

Comment: @user2610146 sorry, forgot to pass `$filmIds` to the closure. I've updated the answer.

Comment: dont't say sorry :) every help is helpfull, thank you.
You gave me a hint, and i done this like:

->where(['id IN' =>$filmIds])

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

if your cakephp version 3.x you can use subqueries in fairly intuitive way

```
$films = TableRegistry::get('Films')->find('highestRated')
->select(['id'])
->limlt(3);

$query = $related->find()
->where(['id' => $films]);
```

Subqueries are accepted anywhere a query expression can be used. For example, in the select() and join() methods. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#subqueries